Defining a measure through integration yields a measure
Let $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a sigma finite measure space.
For $f \in L^1(d \mu)$ and $A \in \mathcal{
A}$, define $\nu(A):=\int_A f d \mu$.
Then $\nu$ is a complex-valued measure.
My attempt:

$\nu(\emptyset)=0$
Let $(B_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of disjoint sets, then
$\nu(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_i)=\int_{\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_i} f d \mu=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int_{B_i} f d\mu= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \nu(B_i)$.

Where we use the sigma finiteness and that $f$ is $L^1$ to ensure the integrals exist.
My Questions is regarding the complex-valuedness.I am not sure what $L^1(d \mu)$ means, the $d \mu$ part to be excactly. How do I show that $\nu$ complex-valued?
My guess would be to assume that $f \in L^1(\mathbb{C})$.

Recall that $f\in L^1(d\mu)$ just means that $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable and such that $$ \int_X \vert f \vert d\mu <\infty. $$ Therefore, $$\nu(A)=\int_A f d\mu$$ is in general a complex number and hence $\nu$ is a complex-valued measure.

@SeverinSchraven Thank you!
